# flushing c input stream after every integer input

Tags: c

i have to make a user input num/percentage pairs. the code looks like:

```
while(choice != 0)
{
  printf("enter number");
  fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);//sizeof(line) is 6
  sscanf(line, "%d\n", choice);
  if(choice > 0)
  {
    printf("enter percentage\n");
    fgets(percent_line, sizeof(percent_line), stdin);//sizeof(percent_line) = 7
    sscanf(percent_line, "%f", &percentage);
    //add to an array holding numbers vs percentages
  }
}
```

the problem with this is that if i enter a string longer than 6 (or 5) at line 5, the remaining string goes into what is scanned at line 10, and if i enter a longer string that 7 (or 6) characters at line 10, the remaining input goes into the input at line 5. i want to destroy any leftover input. how do i do it?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't necessarily the best solution, but another approach might be to use `fscanf()`:

```
while(choice != 0)
{
  printf("enter number");
  fscanf(stdin, "%d", &choice);
  if(choice > 0)
  {
    printf("enter percentage\n");
    fscanf(stdin, "%f", &percentage);
    //add to an array holding numbers vs percentages
  }
}
```

In this way you don't need the temporary `line` and `percent_line` buffers. The `fscanf()` function will automatically keep reading input until it gets what it is looking for - which means that if you just press Enter at the "enter number" prompt, the `fscanf()` function will not return and will keep reading input until you type a number. Also, error handling is not implemented in the above, I leave it as an exercise for the reader to fix the problem that happens when you enter something that *isn't* a number.

(Note that I also changed `choice` to `&choice`, which I think you intended in the first place.)

Answer (score 0):

You can check if there is `\n` in `line` - if not, use `fgetc()` in the loop until `\n` found, then proceed to following input.

Answer (score 0):

i think the latter one does the job pretty well. i dont mind if someone enters "acbgrt" instead of a number, i just want to make the program behave correctly. it will simply convert the string rubbish into 0, and then exit the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this happens is as follows:
fgets reads up to and **only** up to on less than the value specified in the second parameter. In your case, you ask it to read into an array that can hold than 6 values, so it reads 5 values into this array. Anything left over is then left in the buffer to be read later on - which you then read on line 10.

In terms of discarding values, there's no real way that you can "flush" an input buffer, or just clear its contents.
Try the following, to clear the input buffer:

```
while (getc(stdin) != EOF);
clearerr(stdin);
```

Hope this helps.